# Why does Spark (YARN) uses more vCores than total vCores?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

Using something as simple as:

`spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 3g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.7-amzn-0.jar 1000`

I can see on Hadoop dashboard that "vCores Used" is greater than "vCores Total".

How could this happen?

Answer (score 1):

This is because default resource calculator uses memory as the only unit and ignores cores setting.

See [this](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/about_yarn_resource_allocation.html):

> When you use the default resource calculator (DefaultResourceCalculator) resources are allocated based on memory alone.

...and [this](https://blog.cloudera.com/managing-cpu-resources-in-your-hadoop-yarn-clusters/):

> The DefaultResourceCalculator only takes memory into account when doing its calculations. This is why CPU requirements are ignored when carrying out allocations in the CapacityScheduler by default. All the math of allocations is reduced to just examining the memory required by resource-requests and the memory available on the node that is being looked at during a specific scheduling-cycle.